# Recommended books for SharePoint 2010 client object model?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am hoping to get some recommendations on books about SharePoint 2010 client object model. It would be even better if the books have deep dive lessons on the client object model. Please suggest.

P.S. I do not need a book which only talk about SharePoint 2010 client object model. As long as there are good contents about it, I would be happy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the list here. All the books focus on development carry the Client object model topic in depth.

http://wssv4faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v4FAQ/V%20Books.aspx

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=342

Comment: do you have any personal recommendation?

Comment: Not really, I havn't read many